# Customize Login Widget (set Default values in login input fileds)

Tags: users

I added the login widget block to a page

I want to set the default value text "username" and "password" to the input fields.

It currently looks like **1**. I want it to look like **2**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple modules for this (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [In Field Labels](https://www.drupal.org/project/in-field-labels):

  > ... creates integration with the [In-Field Labels](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/) jQuery Plugin.
- [Compact Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/compact_forms):

  > ... presents text fields for selected forms in a more compact fashion using jQuery.
  >
  > The form item/element fields are overlaid with their respective labels. When the user focuses a field the label fades away nicely, and if the field is left empty the label fades back in again.
  >
  > By default, only the user login block is switched to compact style, but the behavior can be added to any form by adding the corresponding CSS ids to the Compact Forms configuration.
  >
  > - Degrades back to the original form when JavaScript is switched off.
  > - Fields like textareas and checkboxes are currently not affected.
  > - Inspired by [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/makingcompactformsmoreaccessible/).

Comment: Thank you. compact_forms worked. A really Easy solution.